# How to get rid of the Gimp 'Tool Options' box?

Tags: gimp

I'm running Gimp 2.10 on macOS and somehow there appeared a super annoying 'Tool Options' box in the upper left corner of the screen:

[image]

It is always on top and hides the Gimp file menu among others. It even stays on top when I switch to another program. I can't move it with the mouse, nor did I find a way to close it. When I click it, Gimp comes on top (a gimmick I really don't need at all). When Gimp is already on top, it appears to have no function whatsoever.

Why is it there? What exactly makes it appear?

How can I get rid of it?

Comment: Simple solution: Quit, save work, reopen.

Answer (score 2):

In the menu go to :
*Windows > Dockable Dialogs*, then deselect "Tool Options".

Comment: It didn't work for me. I cannot select or deselect that option.

Comment: Is the option grayed-out? Which operating system?

Comment: Mac OS Big Sur 11.2.3. It looks like this worked for me: https://www.gimpusers.com/forums/gimp-user/21602-annoying-tool-options-window

Answer (score 1):

This is a great question, because I just encountered the problem, and this question plus the comment by @andreshg112 led me to the solution, in the GIMP bug database.

The Tool Options box in the upper left corner of the screen is related to the *"Tool Options" dockable dialog*, which appears in one or another of the *docks* which GIMP lets you create and populate with *tabs*. In my copy of GIMP 2.10 on macOS, the Tool Options dialog appears in a dock just below the Toolbox. Note the icon next to the Tool Options title in the question's screenshot. It resembles a rectangular canvas on an easel. A smaller version of that same icon appears at the top of the dock where the Tool Options dialog resides. This is the *tab* for the dockable dialog.

The annoying Tool Options obstruction appears when one drags the dockable dialog's tab anywhere outside of the narrow tab row of the dock where it reside. I did this when I was blindly clicking around the tabs trying to figure out GIMP, then moved to the dialog itself with the trackpad button accidentally pressed. When the tab is dragged out of that tab row, a generic document icon appears under the pointer. At the same time, the Tool Options obstruction appears at the top left of the display.

In fact, any dockable dialog can create this obstruction. You can have obstructions from multiple dockable dialogs at once! However, the same fixes seems to work for all of them.

There are two ways to get rid of the obstruction. I use the Tool Options dialog as an example, for clarity, but you can adapt the method for other dockable dialogs and tabs.

The first way is to close the dockable dialog then place it again in its dock.

1. Click on the tab of the actual Tool Options dialog (not the obstruction) to activate it.
2. To the right of the tab, at the top-right corner of the dock area, is an icon with a left-pointing triangle in a square. Hover over this icon. A message, "Configure this tab", appears. Click on the icon. A menu pops up. The first item on the menu reads, "Tool Options Menu".
3. From the original tab configuration menu, select "Close tab". The Tool Option obstruction disappears from the top-left of the display! Hooray! The Tool Options dockable dialog, and its tab, also disappear.
4. Click on the same tab configuration icon. The tab configuration menu pops up again.
5. Drag to the second item in that menu, "Add tab". A submenu pops up, listing all the dockable dialogs. The first entry in this menu is "Tool Options".
6. Continue dragging to "Tool Options" in the submenu. Release the pointer. The menu and submenu disappear. The Tool Options dockable dialog, and its tab, reappear in that dock.

The second way is a bit more obscure, but maybe faster once you are used to it.

1. Click on the tab of the actual Tool Options dialog (not the obstruction) and drag it momentarily into out of the tab area. A generic document icon appears under the pointer.
2. Without releasing the pointer, continue to drag the generic document icon onto the Tool Options tab, back in the dock. Release the drag. The generic icon disappears. The Tool Options obstruction also disappears! Yay!  And the Tool Options dialog is still docked and ready to use.

This Tool Options obstruction is described by [GIMP issue #2731 *Tool Options DND window obscures Mac menu bar*](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/-/issues/2731). (DND perhaps means "drag a[n]d drop"?) It was reported on 31 December 2018, by a user of GIMP 2.10.8 on macOS Mojave 10.14.2. There are 5-10 duplicates of this issue elsewhere in the database. A fix was submitted on 23 January 2022, with a note about GIMP 2.10.30.  However, I still observe the problem with GIMP 2.10.32 on macOS Monterey 12.4.